# How to convert SIF dates into HRF and save them in a macro in Stata?

Tags: date, stata

Stata has some easy functions to convert dates in human readable form (HRF) to Stata internal form (SIF). However, I would like to convert SIF dates into HRF dates. Using `display %td` and related commands, I am able to print the correct dates. But I would like to save the converted dates into a macro.
Unfortunately, the following code snippet does not work:

```
di %tw 2080
local week %tw 2080
di "`week'"
```

---

Update: I am now using the following loop for my original purpose of re-labelling variables.

```
foreach i of varlist week_* {
   local weekcount = substr("`i'", 6, 9)
   local tmp_year = 1960 + int(`weekcount'/52)
   local tmp_week = 1 + `weekcount' - int(`weekcount'/52)*52
   lab var `i' "`tmp_year'w`tmp_week'"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes in two distinct parts.

First, I doubt very much whether your dates correspond to Stata weekly dates. The definition of those weekly dates is

1. Week 1 of any year starts on 1 January, regardless of what day of the week that is.
2. Week 2 and so on start multiples of 7 days later.
3. Week 52 always includes either 8 days (in non-leap years) or 9 days (in leap years).

Thus weeks always nest inside years. Rule #2 by itself is no surprise but rules #1 and #3 often are.

I've not yet encountered any body outside of StataCorp that uses those definitions, although the first time would be instructive!

Second, your syntax doesn't do what you want. Taking your example, what's getting in the way here is that `display`'s job is to interpret what it is given as an instruction to display, not to echo its argument(s) exactly. Using `macro list` (and ignoring irrelevant detail),

```
.  local week %tw 2080

. mac li
_week:          %tw 2080
```

shows that your `local` assignment just copies the text you give. `display` treats that as an instruction, but outside a `display` context, the format does not bite. Piecing together material from the help for `display`, `extended_fcn` and `macro` leads to the syntax

```
. local week : display %tw 2080

. mac li
_week:           2000w1
```

which applies the format and puts the result of the formatting in a macro as requested.

More on `display`: This sequence is instructive.

```
. di "%tw 2080"
%tw 2080

. di %tw "2080"
2080

. di %tw 2080
 2000w1
```

In the first, the format `%tw` is included as part of a literal string and thus is not treated as an instruction. In the second, the format is ignored as relevant only to numeric arguments and thus irrelevant to what is presented as a literal string by virtue of the `" "`. In the third, you would get what you want.

For more on Stata weeks, see the results of

```
. search week, sj

Search of official help files, FAQs, Examples, SJs, and STBs

SJ-12-4 dm0065_1  . . . . . Stata tip 111: More on working with weeks, erratum
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q4/12   SJ 12(4):765                                     (no commands)
        lists previously omitted key reference

SJ-12-3 dm0065  . . . . . . . . . .  Stata tip 111: More on working with weeks
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q3/12   SJ 12(3):565--569                                (no commands)
        discusses how to convert data presented in yearly and weekly
        form to daily dates and how to aggregate such data to months
        or longer intervals

SJ-10-4 dm0052  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Stata tip 68: Week assumptions
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q4/10   SJ 10(4):682--685                                (no commands)
        tip on Stata's solution for weeks and on how to set up
        your own alternatives given different definitions of the
        week
```

If you do this within Stata, you will get clickable links to the articles concerned. The bottom line is one line of advice: refer to weeks by whatever daily date defines them, usually but not necessarily the start or end of the week.

A completely different detail is that you have a wide data structure, which is usually much more problematic in Stata than a long data structure.

NOTE: The question was edited while I was writing this, so some sections refer to material no longer present in the question.

Comment: I am sorry that I have cut the question so much shorter while you were already answering. I also figured that the week format would cause additional trouble for the answers, therefore I edited the question.

Comment: You weren't to know I was working on an answer. More interestingly, if your data source really does use the same definition of week as does Stata, that would be worth documenting.

Comment: I now used the following loop for my purpose which relies on actual SIF weeks (so that there are never more than 52 weeks in a year):
<code>foreach i of numlist 2080 {
 local tmp_year = 1960 + int(`i'/52)
 local tmp_week = 1 + `i' - int(`i'/52)*52
 di "`tmp_year'w"`tmp_week'"
}</code>

Comment: I'd edit your question as that code doesn't display legibly (not least because Stata uses a opening single quote and so does Stack Overflow). That looks like a loop over one item!

Comment: My source "kind of" uses the Stata definition of weeks as I have deliberately altered the dates (relying on your articles btw). But I had to convert from spell to wide format for another analysis using `R`...